# Simulating joints in rigid body physics

Tags: classical-mechanics, simulations, rigid-body-dynamics

When simulating rigid body physics with joints(say unconstrained for simplicity) you normally have a constraint force binding the two objects together applied at the point of the joint.

This results in a system with too many degrees of freedom so we use that the force does no work to provide an additional constraint.

I'm confused on this for two reasons.

1. How do we define work in the context of rigid bodies?
2. How do we know that not doing any work retains the systems kinetic energy?

It's also not clear to me if one object could gain energy while the other would lose it or if both objects would retain the same kinetic energies.